# How to upgrade Appium 1.4.13

Tags: github, appium

I have Appium version `1.4.8` installed in my machine ( mac os). Appium ommunity just released [here](https://discuss.appium.io/t/appium-1-4-13-released/6258)! Now I have source in my machine for `1.4.13`. How do I launch Appium `1.4.13` GUI? or how do

How do I get the .App from the code?

Appium website is still showing `1.4.8` for download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the Answer [here](https://discuss.appium.io/t/upgrade-appium-client-to-latest-appium-version/6054)!
Here are the steps to re-config your Appium (Mac app/Windows EXE) client point to latest Appium version 1.4.11.

1. Clone this Appium git to your local git clone https://github.com/appium/appium.git
2. Once the download is complete, Run reset.sh
3. Open Appium Client
4. Select "Developer settings" and enable it.
5. Select Use External NodeJS Binary to "Your local node bin folder path"
6. Select Use External Appium Package to "Your Appium Local clone folder path"
7. Start the Appium Server.

You should see the latest version of Appium on the client like below

> info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.11 (REV 460994a14dfb20b2d55ff14b99c0d31f6af5a9e2)
>   info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723

Answer (score 0):

Latest version 1.4.13 available [here](https://bitbucket.org/appium/appium.app/downloads/)

But I would suggest not to upgrade to the same since it seems to be unstable and a lot of features are fishy even after rollbacks applied.